# buildSessionFactory throws "the network adapter could not establish the connection" error in junit test mode which was fine in live mode

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jsp, junit

In unit test, I got stuck.
When I use dao the buildSessionFactory method throws "the network adapter could not establish the connection" error.
This works fine in live mode.
Here is the unit test code.

```
public class OAuth20Test {  
    
private UserDetailsDAOI userDetailsDAO;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp () throws Exception {
    this.userDetailsDAO = new UserDetailsDAO();
}    

@Test                                               
@DisplayName("Simple checkAuthGrant should work")   
public void testCheckAuthGrant() {
   if (this.userDetailsDAO == null) {
       System.out.println("user dao is null");
   } else {
       assertEquals(true, userDetailsDAO.checkAuthGrant("*****", "*****", "*****", "*****"),      
    "Regular checkAuthGrant should work");          
   }
}
```

This is getMainDBSessionFactory function which is in the userDetialsDAO

```
long lStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

Configuration mainDBConfiguration = getMainDBSessionConfiguration();

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

String dbType = DAOConfiguration.getString("dao.db.type", "");

String mainHibernateConfigFileName = "hibernate-config-main-" + dbType + ".xml";

   
  ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
      .applySettings(mainDBConfiguration.getProperties())
      .configure(mainHibernateConfigFileName)
      .build();
  
  return mainDBConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

buildSessionFactory function is from package org.hibernate.cfg

And the error occurs in `mainDBConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)`

I have found that the reason why this error occurs is that the JUnit is not compatible with creating the session factory.

What is the approach to cope with that?

Comment: Please the `buildSessionFactory`  implementation, where it actually throws error.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri thanks for your interest, could you please check this?